# Saving contacts with Android phonegap

Tags: database, cordova, contacts

Am building a phonegap app and i need to save all contacts that are read with phonegap in device.

So How can I save all contacts that are read with phonegap in device on database app ?

I've tried this:

```
                function onSuccess(contacts) {

                        if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers != null){

                            for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++){

                                var phonenumber = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value;
                                phonenumber = phonenumber.replace(/[()-]/g,"");
                                var phonenumberFinal = phonenumber.replace(/ /g,'');

                                    var contactosTodos = [nomeContacto, phonenumberFinal];

                                    //for (var a=0; a<contactosTodos.length; a++){
                                        dbase.transaction(function (tx){
                                            tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CONTACTOS');
                                            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTOS (nome, numero);");
                                            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO CONTACTOS (name, number) VALUES (?, ?);", [ contactosTodos[j] , contactosTodos[j=+1] ]);
                                        });
                                    //}

                                }
                        }
                    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you taken a look at the [Contacts API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts)? Are you trying to save them to database on the same app, different app, or remote server?

Comment: @AndrewLively I already retrieve all contacts from the cellphone but now i need to save them to database on the same app...

Comment: Have you tried the [Storage API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)?

Comment: @AndrewLively, can you have an idea how can i do that? in code, please...!

Comment: I have an idea on how to do it, but I'm not writing your code for you, the PhoneGap documentation does a very good job at explaining how to do this. Once you get something started and it still isn't working with the code you tried then post the code and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @AndrewLively ... now ... what you gonna say ???

Comment: Are you getting any sort of errors? What does your database look like after this function is called? Where are you getting `dbase` from? I don't see it being declared or connected to a database. Also, I'm not an SQL guy, but why are you dropping and recreating your table every time you iterate in the loop?